# Bash pulling elements from a function

Tags: bash, function

I'm curious to know if you can pull lines from a function in bash. Say I have this function:

```
error_fn()
{
    echo "You need at least 2 command line arguments!"
    echo "Program existing because you said you had a typo, please try agian"
    echo "Sorry, one or both of the files that you entered was a directory, please try agian"
    echo "Sorry, one or both files were not located, please try again"
}
```

Is there a way to pull the first echo statement (echo "You need at least 2 command line arguments!") from this array?

I have tried using:

```
error_fn $1
error_fn ("$1")
```

but this seems to just output all the echo statements in the function. Any ideas?

Comment: `error_fn | head -n 1`?

Comment: This does in fact pull the first one but only the first one. But later on in my code I want to call the second element and from what I know head limits what you can see. So if I used head -n 2 it will show both lines and not just the second one. Piping to grep also works but it's not very consistent.

Comment: you can use `sed '2!d'`, `sed '3!d'` etc in that case.. but you can probably pass an argument to the function and use [switch case](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/420/control-structures/9948/switch-statement-with-case#t=201608030436307623055)

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think to use sed.

Comment: A *heredoc* is the easiest way to handle boiler-plate text, much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You could do your `error_fn()` similar to the following and pass the index value `idx` (zero-based, e.g. `0 - 3`) as the argument to `error_fn()`to have the corresponding error output.

```
error_fn() {
    array=( "You need at least 2 command line arguments!"
            "Program existing because you said you had a typo, please try agian"
            "Sorry, one or both of the files that you entered was a directory, please try agian"
            "Sorry, one or both files were not located, please try again" )
    idx=$(($1))
    if [ '0' -le "$idx" -a "$idx" -le '3' ]
    then
        printf "error: %s\n" "${array[idx]}"
    else
        printf "error: function index '%d' out of range.\n" "$idx"
    fi
}
```

Look it over and let me know if you have questions.

As for a general error/usage function, I generally prefer as much of the boiler-plate as possible being in a *heredoc* while having the ability to pass an error message as well through `$1` for the funciton. Example:

```
usage() {

    local ecode=${2:-0}     ## set exit code '0' by default

    test -n "$1" && printf "\n %s\n" "$1" >&2  ## print error msg (if any)

## heredoc of usage information
cat >&2 << USG

usage: ${0//*\//} _required_input_, etc..

This script ... (give description)

Options:

    -h  |  --help  program help (this file)

USG

    exit $ecode;
}
```

It use would be to display usage information by default, display an error in addition to the usage if an error string is given as agrument 1, and finally to set the exit code for the program `0` by default but it will set any numeric argument as the exit code if passed as the second argument. Examples

```
[ -z "$1" ] && usage "warning: insufficient input."  # General usage use.

[ -d "neededdir" ] || mkdir -p neededdir     # error on exit and set ecode 2
[ -d "neededdir" } || usage "error: unable to create 'neededdir'." 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is just another command creating output. You may parse it.

```
error_fn | head -n 1
```

However, if you rewrite the function to take an argument and to display an error message relating to that argument, it will probably do what you intend it to do:

```
function error_fn {
  err="$1"

  case "$err" in
    EREFP) echo "Error: refining particles failed" >&2 ;;
    ECYCE) echo "Error: number of cycles exceeded" >&2 ;;
    EHUPM) echo "Error: hangup misdirected, dangling receiver" >&2 ;;
    *)     echo "Error: something's wrong (code:$err)" >&2 ;;
  esac
}

if ! refine_particles; then
  error_fn EREFP
else if ! hang_up_projections; then
  error_fn EHUPM
fi
```